# Error using QuickFix with VC++ in Visual Studio 2010 (utility.obj)

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, tcp, quickfix

Here it goes:

1. I downloaded the QuickFix source, built it using CMake and got the .sln file.
2. Then I opened the .sln file in VC++ 2010 and built the project named "quickfix_vs10"
   (actually i built a library named quickFix.lib) and got some warnings but the build was 
   successful.
3. I then used this .lib file in another project using #pragma comment(lib, "quickFix.lib")
4. Whenever I declare an instance of class FIX::TransactTime in my project, I get numerous 
   link time errors. All of them have to do with an unresolved token in utility.obj.
   These errors don't come if I use any other class.

One of those errors is:

> quickFix.lib(Utility.obj) : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000426) "extern "C" int __stdcall getpeername(unsigned int,struct sockaddr *,int *)" (?getpeername@@$$J212YGHIPAUsockaddr@@PAH@Z) referenced in function "char const * __cdecl FIX::socket_peername(int)" (?socket_peername@FIX@@$$FYAPBDH@Z)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you need to link `"Ws2_32.lib"`

see [getpeername](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference

Comment: Not a very explanatory answer but it told me about "Ws2_32.lib" which solved my problem. I just introduced the line #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib") and it solved my problem. I got the idea of doing so through link:  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?445581-RESOLVED-cannot-find-ws2_32.lib-for-socket-programming